# Binary classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, binary-data

I have a binary classification problem. 
My inputs consist of a time-series of values plus some binary values.
For real-valued inputs I would usually use a neural network, while for binary-values inputs I would use either a neural network with a step function or some other method fit for binary inputs (like a maximum entropy classifier)

In the case where input types are mixed what architecture should be used?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  None of the methods you mention care whether your *inputs* are categorical or real valued.

Comment: Do you have a) two time series, one of binary values to predict and one of inputs, or b) binary values associated with whole stretches of input values organized in a time series?

Answer (score 1):

You could continue to use NN with the binary values as an additional input feature. The activation function would be a sigmoid. You will end up with an output vector where the values  where the class values with either be high or low. You could then classify the high values as 1 and the low values a 0